# Formik - React - How to get out of the onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I'm using Formik in my React app.

In my `onSubmit`, I'm making a API call to a service, if that fails I'd like the rest of the `onSubmit` to stop right there and do nothing else - how can I implement such a break?

e.g.

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { name: '' },
    validationSchema: mySchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
        setIsSubmitting(true);

        let details = await axios.get(`${process.env.MY_API}/release/${values.number}`)
                                 .catch(//Don't go any further)
```

I tried rejecting the promise, return and break but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox for this, that might help solve issue

Comment: Why not use `await` if your function is marked `async` anyway? Wrap your API call in `try/catch`, then simply `return` on error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async/await` or `then/catch`.

*Then/Catch:*

```js
axios.get().then(() => /* Submitting */).catch(() => /* Error */)
```

*Async/Await:*

```js
try {
  const result = await axios.get();
  if (result?.success === true) {  // Based on what the API returns
    /* Submitting */
  } else {
    /* Error */
  }
} catch (errorMessage) {

}
```